# Can I use the autocorrelation function on non-stationary time series?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, acf-pacf

First of all I apologize because I don't have a lot of knowledge in the field.  I would like to know if it is possible to use the ACF function in R to find the autocorrelation coefficient with a lag of 1 despite the fact that the time series is not stationary?